# Backbutton event preventDeafult [phonegap + onsenUI]

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I'm building a simple app with phonegap + OnsenUI but Ive noticed th OnsenUI is taking control of my BackButton event so i cant use `evt.preventDefault()`;

This is what im trying to do:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonFire, false);
function backButtonFire(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  alert(1);
}
```

When the event is fired i see the alert(1) but the app still going to the background.

How can I use `preventDefault` in this situation?

Comment: Did you bind that eventListener inside the eventListenener for the DeviceReady Event?

What exactly do you want to achive? Prevent the buttom from going pages back or from moving the app to the background? The Background/Closing can not be prevented as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I found this at the onsenui.js:

```
  /**
   * Disable this framework to handle cordova "backbutton" event.
   */
  disableDeviceBackButtonHandler: function() {
    this._getOnsenService().DeviceBackButtonHandler.disable();
  },
```

so i just used:

```
ons.disableDeviceBackButtonHandler();
```

Now its working great but it disables all the OnsenUI backbutton handler settings so you need to set one by yourself.